# PostgreSQL ETL to SQL Server 2014 using SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssis-2012, postgresql-9.4

I have a package that uses an odbc connection to retrieve data from a PostgreSQL table and then I sort it and perform a outer merge join so I can bring in only the fields that I haven't put into the system. It has been working all day and now the SSIS job just hangs and no records are being put in. The job hangs before it ever gets to the merge join. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you show the warning text on the postgres source?

Comment: I'm not getting a warning text in any of the logs. The process just hangs.